# Program crashes (Dynamic memory allocation)

Tags: c++

I just started reading about dynamic memory allocation and for some reason my program crashes.

```
void getSpace(int *ptr)
{
   ptr = new int [100];
}

void getData(int *ptr)
{
   cin >> *(ptr);
   cin >>*(ptr+1);
}
int main()
{
   int *ptr = NULL;
   getSpace(ptr);
   getData(ptr);
}
```

But for some reason, this one doesn't. It seems like if I declare the pointer at the same function as where I get the array into the heap size I wanted, it doesn't crashes.

Comment: hint: `ptr` is `nullptr` in `getData`

Comment: maybe you should delete your newly allocated ptr after your done with it because it can cause memory leaks

Comment: The pointer `ptr` should be [passed by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) to `getSpace()`. Something like `getSpace(int **ptr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int* ptr` is local copy of pointer, so you only allocate the memory inside scope of `getSpace`, and you assign it into `ptr` variable, but it is local to the `getScope`, and so the `main` function does not see the allocation. You should either do `int** ptr` and do `*ptr = new int[100];` or `int*& ptr` and then `ptr = new int[100];`

Comment: I see. I was thinking that the pointer points to the address of ptr, thus if I allocate memory for the pointer, it automatically allocates memory for ptr as well.

Comment: Its not about allocating memory for the pointer but you are passing the pointer by value to getSpace().

Comment: @drescherjm thank you, I will update the answer to be more presise.

Comment: I think I get it. Because the variable is a pointer, so when I do getSpace(&ptr), I passed on the address of the pointer. While in the getSpace function, it receives the address of the pointer, but because the variable is a pointer, so its void getSpace(string **ptr). Like it means the pointer variable points to the address of a pointer. Sorry it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Which in the other way if I'm just passing a normal variable which is not a pointer, then I don't need ** because the variable isn't a pointer. only one * because it points to the address of the variable. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
void getSpace(int **ptr)
{
  *ptr = new int [100];
}
```

and call it:

```
getSpace(&ptr);
```